# Non-Mozilla equivalents of MozAfterPaint?

Tags: javascript, browser, reflow, web-performance

I'm looking for a way to measure reaction times (how quickly a user can press a key after some image is presented). Measuring the time of the key press is obviously no problem, but I haven't figured out how to measure the time of the paint event/presentation of the stimulus. Mozilla's MozAfterPaint seems perfect for this, but are there equivalents for other browsers?

Comment: [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/MozAfterPaint) on this non-standard event says `requestAnimationFrame(()=>setTimeout(cb,0))` should be used. I wonder if you would have more precision with postMessage instead of setTimeout though, but I'm not entirely sure postMessage will even wait enough to be sure painting has occured...